# Skipping a department lunch during two week notice

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I put in my two week notice last week. I honestly have always felt out of place in this department. My last two weeks happen to fall on one of our department lunches that we plan every once in awhile and I have one more week left before beginning my new job. Would it be in bad taste to skip this lunch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be in bad taste to skip this lunch?

**No, no harm at all**.

At this point you are leaving, no one should be surprised by this.  These company / group lunches are typically for team building, information sharing, and such.

It won't hurt you obviously to go, but at this point *if you want to skip it there would be no harm* -- based on my experience.